# PNG image distorted with GD

Tags: php, gd

I am attempting to build an image with GD. Part of this building is to add a PNG with some transparent space to an image. I am working on 2 different servers.

Server 1, which builds the image flawlessly has the following config:
PHP 5.4.21
GD 2.1.0 PNG Support enabled (with libPNG)

Server 2, which is having an issue:
php 5.2.17
GD 2.0.34 PNG Support enabled (no libPNG)

This second server is distorting the image so it looks like this:

[image: Distorted]

Here is the original:

[image]

It is maintains the correct height, but the width is distorted and the lines appear.

My original code looks like this:

```
$et_marker = @imagecreatefrompng('images/et_marker.png');
...
imagecopy($chart, $et_marker, $left, $mk_top, 0, 0, imagesx($et_marker), imagesy($et_marker));
```

Then I thought maybe it would work better if I converted the PNG to a TrueColor image, so I changed the code to this:

```
$et_marker_raw = @imagecreatefrompng('images/et_marker.png');
$width = imagesx($et_marker_raw);
$height = imagesy($et_marker_raw);
$et_marker = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$bg_col = imagecolorallocatealpha($et_marker, 10, 10, 10, 127);
imagefill($et_marker, 0, 0, $bg_col);
imagecopyresampled($et_marker, $et_marker_raw, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
```

That was the only idea I had.

I cannot find enough info about libPNG to determine if not having this is the issue.

Using Imagemagick is not an option here.

How can I load this PNG so it does not distort like the above sample?

Comment: I understand the problem, but can you tell us what's the final idea ? What are you trying to accomplish ? Maybe there are quicker ways that can be found to accomplish what are you trying to do, but for that, we need to know what are you looking for.

Comment: I'm betting installing libpng will clear up the issue.